# Nginx access_by_lua_block not executed in case of 3XX redirects

Tags: nginx, lua, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-location, openresty

I am using the `access_by_lua_block` in my nginx configuration to add/modify custom request headers (let's say `ngx.req.set_header("foo", "bar")`). I am accessing these headers within the `header_filter_by_lua_block` as `ngx.var["http_foo"]` just before returning any response to the client.
This works fine in case of passing the request to upstream, however it doesn't work in case of redirects.
So basically,

This works (No redirect).

```
location /abc {
   proxy_pass some_upstream;

   access_by_lua_block {
      ngx.req.set_header("foo", "bar")
   }

   header_filter_by_lua_block {
     ngx.header["foo2"] = ngx.var["http_foo"] # this is correctly getting the value of "foo" header set above
   }
}
```

This doesn't work (With Redirect)

```
location /abc {
   access_by_lua_block {
      ngx.req.set_header("foo", "bar")
   }

   header_filter_by_lua_block {
     ngx.header["foo2"] = ngx.var["http_foo"] # this is not getting the value of "foo" header set above
   }

   return 301 xyz.com;
}
```

The access_by_lua_block is not getting executed in case of redirects only (return 301 statement). I don't understand why so? Because access_by_lua_block has a execution priority before the content phase ([link](https://openresty-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Directives/))

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understand, execution of `return` directive happens within the rewrite phase, and access phase doesn't executed at all in this case. You can try to change `access_by_lua_block` to `rewrite_by_lua_block` and see what happens.

## Update

First attempt to solve the problem gives nothing. Indeed, as lua-ngx-module documentation for `rewrite_by_lua` [states](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#rewrite_by_lua_block):

> Note that this handler always runs *after* the standard ngx_http_rewrite_module.

What else you could try is to do the redirect inside the `rewrite_by_lua_block`:

```
location /abc {
   rewrite_by_lua_block {
      ngx.req.set_header("foo", "bar")
      ngx.redirect("xyz.com", 301)
   }

   header_filter_by_lua_block {
     ngx.header["foo2"] = ngx.var["http_foo"] # this is not getting the value of "foo" header set above
   }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. I tried rewrite_by_lua_block as well, still the request header is not accessible.

Comment: @VinayMundada One more try, check the updated answer please. Again, this is just a guess.